# Webapi controller changes property names to lower case

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have class like this:

```
public class Creature
{
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public bool Upgrade { get; set; }
    public int Attack { get; set; }
    public int Defence { get; set; }
    public int MinDamage { get; set; }
    public int MaxDamage { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Hp { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}

public class CreaturesList
{
    public List<Creature> Creatures { get; set; }
}

 public class ReadCreatures : IReadCreatures
    {
        public Creature GetCreature(string name)
        {
            var result = GetData(); 
            return result.Creatures.Where(w => w.Name.ToLower().Equals(name.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        protected CreaturesList GetData()  => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CreaturesList>(heroes3wiki.Properties.Resources.Creatures);
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
public class CreaturesController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ILogger<CreaturesController> _logger;
    private readonly IReadCreatures _getCreatures;

    public CreaturesController(ILogger<CreaturesController> logger , IReadCreatures getCreatures)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _getCreatures = getCreatures;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Creature> Get() => _getCreatures.GetCreatures();

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public Creature Get(string name) => _getCreatures.GetCreature(name);

}
```

as you can see i have all properties in Creature class first Capital letter. But when i call this endpoint i receive data like below:

```
{"town":"Castle","name":"Pikeman","level":1,"upgrade":false,"attack":4,"defence":5,"minDamage":1,"maxDamage":3,"speed":4,"hp":10,"cost":60}
```

Can anyone explain me it this is how it should be or I have error somewhere?

Comment: Because that's how ASP.NET Core's `JsonOutputFormatter` writes JSON values. But why do you care?

Comment: @IanKemp because then on the frondend side in my angular.io app i have interface where i also have properties with capital case

Comment: Which is nonstandard JSON. JSON is camelCase for properties, C# is CamelCase. Hence why ASP.NET Core transforms from C# style to JSON style.

Comment: @IanKemp JSON literally doesn't care about the capitalization of properties. Or if you use `snake_case` or whatever you want, as long as it is a valid identifier.

Comment: JSON serializers and deserializers very much care about capitalisation. And I didn't say it was invalid, I said it was nonstandard.

Answer (score 6):

Asp.Net Core changed the default behavior (I think between 2.x and 3.x).

If you want to keep the names of your properties (and not have the capitalization changed), you need to set the `PropertyNamingPolicy`  to `null`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        });
}
```

From the docs on [JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamingpolicy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_PropertyNamingPolicy):

> A property naming policy, or `null` to leave property names unchanged.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to set it to `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` - `null` is the default camelCase, IIRC.

Comment: @IanKemp Looking at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamingpolicy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_PropertyNamingPolicy), the value of `PropertyNamingPolicy` is "A property naming policy, or null to leave property names unchanged."

Comment: @IanKemp No, you are wrong. It needs to be `null` so that properties are unchanged. `CamalCase` still makes it lowercase.